# check if file exists on the sub directory

Tags: php

[image]I tried to check for the existence of a file:

```
$center='412';
$dl ='download/D'.$center.'.zip';
if (file_exists($dl)) {
```

if I execute those script on the localhost, it's run properly or found the file, but if I execute on the web server, it's goes wrong or file not found. then I change the script as follows.

```
$center='412';
$dl ='/home/a1527507/public_html/sm/download/D'.$center.'.zip';
if (file_exists($dl)) {
```

a1527507 is my user id. it's still does not run properly. is there anything wrong from my script. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `if(file_exists( getcwd() . 'download/D'.$center.'.zip' )){..`

Comment: 2nd script will definitely not work because `file_exists` doesn't work on `http`

Comment: Make sure you are being case sensitive on the web server. Windows is case insensitive on files and folders, but linux is not. It also can be a file permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 potential issues here.  The first script uses a relative directory.  It assumes that 'download/D' is in the same working directory as the executing script.  That may not be the case on your server.  The second issue is that you are taking

```
$dl ='http://www.comze.com/sm/download/D'.$center.'.zip';
```

and checking for it's existence on the server which is most certainly will not as it's a URL.

I would recommend that you use an absolute directory to make sure you're checking the correct location for the file "/usr/local/nginx/html/downloads...".  That will likely resolve this problem.

Comment: i add an image on my question above my be can help you ti imagine my server and i change my script : /home/a1527507/public_html/sm/download/D'.$center.'.zip';    a1527507 is my username. but it still not working properly

Comment: The image above shows a directory tree starting with "root/".  You should also make sure your runtime allows access to that directory.  Maybe do a trial run using `echo getcwd()` to see from where the script is executing.

Comment: I was wrong writing the script, the file extension must fit the existing capital letters in the folder. php is case sensitive. the path is correct. Now the application is running as I expected. thanks to your support.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use the first script listed. 
The issue here may be lack of directory permissions so you may need to use your ftp client to reconfigure the permissions for all files in the folder you are searching through.  Try 7 for user 5 for group and 5 for world. Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions